# Finding the maximum perimeter of a rectangle inside of an enclosed region

Tags: calculus, optimization

A rectangle is to be inscribed in the region enclosed by the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis and the parabola $y=(x-1)^2$. What is the maximum perimeter that such a rectangle can have?

Seems straightforward, however, our Perimeter equation is $P(x) = 2x + 2(x-1)^2$ (here, $x$ is the side of the rectangle along the $x$-axis, and $y$ is the height, which we substituted with the parabola equation).

This equation has an absolute max at $x=0,1$ with value $2$. By itself, that makes sense, but in the context of this problem, these points corresponds to a rectangle with either a base of $0$ or a height of $0$, which then wouldn't really be a rectangle. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are making good sense, you might want to double check that you do actually want the max perimeter and not the minimum.

Comment: Indeed, this was a question on an old exam I came across. The instructor probably meant to write minimum.

Comment: check your calc for max.

Comment: How does the equation have an absolute max at x= 0,1 ? Are you referring to P(x) which is a quadratic and has a minimum when x = 1/2?

Comment: The perimeter function is a quadratic parabola that opens upwards. Thus the vertex would be the minimum perimeter. No calculus is needed.

If you wanted to use calculus: You could find when  '() = 0 which is when  = 1/2 which is the minimum perimeter when you sub x = 1/2 into P(x)

Answer (score 0):

I think the exercise is to maximize the perimeter of a rectangle under the parabola $y=(x-1)^2$ in the first Cartesian quadrant.
[image]

One way to do this is by Lagrangian multipliers.  We seek to maximize the function $x+y$ subject to the constraint $y-(x-1)^2=0$.  We thus write the Lagrangian,
$$
\mathcal L=x+y +\lambda (y-(x-1)^2)\\
\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial x}=1+2\lambda (1-x)=0\\
\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial y}=1 +\lambda=0\\
$$
$$
\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial {\lambda}}=y-(x-1)^2=0
$$
Thus $\lambda=-1$, $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Note that $(1/2, 1/4)$ is the absolute minimum, not maximum. So this method gives the same answer as the usual calculus one method of finding critical points (albeit, the perimeter is $2$ times your function).